# Why don't child elements no placed in BoxSizer

Tags: python, wxpython

buttons can't stay less than minsize, how to fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6K9f.png)

```
def makeButtons(self):
    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=5, vgap=5)
    sizer.Add(self.makeButton(), pos = (0, 0))
    sizer.Add(self.makeButton(), pos = (0, 1))
    sizer.Add(self.makeButton(), pos = (0, 2))
    sizer.Add(self.makeButton(), pos = (0, 3))
    sizer.Add(self.makeButton(), pos = (0, 4))
    return sizer

def makeButton(self, label=""):
    button = wx.Button(self, label = label)
    button.SetSizeHints(20,-1,-1,-1)
    return button
```

Comment: can you explain more? add your code?

Comment: I get it, use SetSizeHints(small_width, -1, -1, -1), but cannot apply it for GridBagSizer

Comment: I try to make this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/612039) using GridBagSizer